# When using flutter_blue package and trying to build android appBuild fails with an exception. This is happening only when I am importing this package

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle, dart-pub, flutter-android

I am trying to use flutter_blue package in flutter application. It is easily added to the dependencies but when I try to build the app after adding this package an exception occurs. I have done all the required setups for this package like, setting `minSdkVersion 19` and asking for permissions for bluetooth.

Bellow, I have shared screenshot as well as text of the error that is coming as well some other codes

[DebugConsole Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KT9Ni.jpg)

**DebugConsole**

```
Launching lib\main.dart on RMX3171 in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
Parameter format not correct -

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
   > Android resource linking failed
     ERROR:D:\learning projects\bluetooth\project\build\app\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:59: AAPT: error: unexpected element <uses-permission> found in <manifest><application>.

     ERROR:D:\learning projects\bluetooth\project\build\app\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:60: AAPT: error: unexpected element <uses-permission> found in <manifest><application>.

     ERROR:D:\learning projects\bluetooth\project\build\app\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:61: AAPT: error: unexpected element <uses-permission> found in <manifest><application>.


* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 19s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

**android/app/scr/main/AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.project">
   <application
        android:label="project"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />  
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />  
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>  
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**android/app/built.gradle**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
   // throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.project"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

**android/build.gradle**
I have not created any changes here, but I am sharing this. May be it is helpul.

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**pubspec.yaml**

```
name: project
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.6 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_blue: ^0.8.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

I only have a main.dart file, which has nothing to do with the flutter_blue package for now so I have not posted its code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving the permissions outside of application tag, like this.

```
<manifest>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />  
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />  
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>  
<application>
     ....
</application>
<manifest>
```